# Xamarin Forms - Visual Studio 2019 build IPA file for testing

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, ipa

I've read and reread a lot of Microsoft official documentation but they are all abysmally outdated or just simply wrong.

 
Is there a guide how to generate IPA file on Visual Studio 2019 for it to be published on the client phone?

**They do not want it on iTunes Store, they just want to install the app on their iPhones.**


How to set up the provisioning profile (and where - XCode/VSforMac/VS2019) which certificate to choose from (screenshots on Microsoft documentation page do not correspond with iOS Developer Program site)
Pair to Mac is up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a guide how to generate IPA file on Visual Studio 2019

It's almost same as described in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows#creating-an-ipa).

Config the options in iOS iPA option and remember to **check the Build iTunes Package Archive(iPA)**. **Build** your app and then you can find the `ipa` file in `your iOS project` --> `Bin`--> `iPhone` --> `Release` folder.

[image: screenshot]

> They do not want it on iTunes Store, they just want to install the app
>   on their iPhones.

They can choose to install the app through `iTunes Store`(.ipa), `testFlight`(upload to Itunes Connect) or some other `third-part tools`.

> How to set up the provisioning profile

Create your `Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile` in the Apple Developer Center as mention in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution?tabs=windows#setting-up-for-distribution), then download it in Visual-Studio(`Tools` --> `options` --> `Xamarin` --> `Apple Account`). Don't forget to add the UUID of devices you want to test to the certification.

You can choose `Automatic Provisioning` option and then visual-studio will auto select the certification for you.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The only thing that is bugging me now is the UUID of devices.
We don't know how many users this app is gonna have (probably couple dozen) and we do not know any UUIDs of their iPhones.
We hoped that it would work the same way as is on Andoird, building an .apk file and downloading it to the devices.
We tested every feature we have on iOS simulator Paired to Mac machine, so we don't have a physical iPhone to test on...

Comment: You can't do that with a personal apple developer account. What you need is a [Apple Developer Enterprise Account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/).

Comment: So my Apple Developer Program account (the $99 one) does nothing for me? 
I cannot release the IPA for client that way?

Comment: You can release your app through AppStroe. You can add the UUID of device for internal test(up to 100 devices) while you say  you do not know any UUIDs of their iPhones.

Comment: So I can release the App WITHOUT store just by knowing the UUIDs of iPhones of users?

Comment: Yes, user can install the ipa file which device UUID is included in the Provisioning Profile and there is a limit that only 100 device UUIDs can be added to the Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Thank you very much. I honestly hope this will solve this 'issue'.

Comment: @StefanSrbljanin Don't  forget to upvote/mark this answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to create AdHoc distribution certificate and You have to  add UDID of a client device in Appstore account

Comment: So, I'll need to manually add all of the clients iPhones to AdHoc distribution before generating a IPA file?
I cannot just give the IPA file to clients who want to install the app on their phone to use and test?

Comment: No, For that you must have to set Test Flight

Comment: "First, build your final distributable in the IDE, then submit your app to Apple through either the Application Loader, or the archive function in Xcode."
Does this mean that I have to publish it through Apple Store?
The client explicitly does NOT want to do that.